# simple WHILE loop

Tags: java

Suppose you have one cent ($0.01) in a sock. Each day you double the amount of money you have in the sock. Thus on day one you have one cent, on day two you have two cents ($0.02), on day three you have four cents ($0.04), and so forth.

The doubleEachDay method takes a double value, jackpot, as its input argument, and calculates the number of days needed to reach or exceed the jackpot amount, starting at 0.01 and doubling each day. The method returns the number of days required for doubling; this value should be stored in the integer variable numDays.

Finish the doubleEachDay method below.

This is my code,

```
public int doubleEachDay(double jackpot) {
  double amount = 0.01;
  int numDays = 0;

while(amount <= jackpot){
  amount=(amount*2);
    numDays++;
}

 return numDays;
}
```

My code keeps producing 1 more day than the actual answer. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The reason is that floating points are inaccurate. For instance, 0.01*2 may equal 0.0199999999 instead of 0.02.

Instead of using doubles, you should use an integer with the number of cents, so 1, 2, 4 and so on.

The other reason is that you wrote `amount <= jackpot` instead of `amount < jackpot`. This means that you'll count the day that `amount == jackpot` as one extra day.

Alternatively, instead of doing `amount < jackpot`, you can do something like `jackpot - amount > 0.0000001` to counteract the slight amount of inaccuracy.

Comment: @user2086204 While floating point inaccuracy is a thing you need to worry about, I just realized the real reason why your code is wrong. LOL. Check out the edited question ;)

Answer (score -1):

I assumed that you want to count the number of days that the amount is totally EQUAL to jackpot.

just change the loop condition into this:

```
while (amount != jackpot)...
```

Comment: This won't get past the floating point inaccuracy issue pointed out by Patashu.

Comment: Also, this won't work if the jackpot is not .01 to some power of two.

Comment: This will sometimes solve the problem, and sometimes make it worse.